# Select elements with attribute data-url using HTMLAgilityPack

Tags: c#, .net, html-agility-pack

I'm writing a little Download-Roboter, that is searching for links in lower layers for it self.

What i need to find are all links in an html-Page (the links to .jpg files as well as the links to .pgn, .pdf, .html,.... - files)

I´m using the html-agilitypack to find all a-href links.

Sample code:

```
foreach (HtmlNode link in htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]"))
{
    HtmlAttribute attribute = link.Attributes["href"];
    links.Add(attribute.Value);
}
```

But i want to find the data-urls as well.

What XPath-syntax do i have to use to find data-urls. An example data-url in an htmlcode:

```
    <div class="cbreplay" data-url="2012\edmonton\partien.pgn"></div>
```

I need the "2012\edmonton\partien.pgn" out of this example. How can i realize this with XPath syntax?

Best greetings, if i made some bad mistakes, tell me. This is my first question ever.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The following should do what you want:

```
foreach (HtmlNode divNode in htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@data-url]"))
{
    HtmlAttribute attribute = divNode.Attributes["data-url"];
    links.Add(attribute.Value);
}
```

Effectively, the statement `//div[@data-url]` should select all nodes with a data-url attribute. We then pull out this attribute.

If there are nodes other than divs with this attribute, then `//*[@data-url]` should do the trick.

Comment: it may be more flexible to use `*` instead of `div` - `"//*[@data-url]"`. Those darn html authors keep changing their html!